# Find the execution flow when an API is called from postman

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, http

Is it possible to call an api such as "localhost/calculate" using PostMan and find out which classes or methods are called in order?

It would be like (GetCalculateResult(), Calculate.cs) -> (MathLogic(), Math.cs) and etc?

I want to know the way so it will be easier when I'm trying to understand how others codes work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that using the `call stack` functionality in `visual studio` and `WinDbg`

**Visual Studio:**

By using the Call Stack window, you can view the `function or procedure calls` that are `currently on the stack`. The Call Stack window shows the order in which methods and functions are getting called. The call stack is a good way to examine and understand the execution flow of an app.

**Implementation:**

To view the call stack:

> Start the debugger and stop at a breakpoint.

[image]

You can get [`more details here in the offical document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2022)

**WinDbg:**

Another tool you can use to check your application call stack strace mecanism using [`WinDbg tool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/calls-window)

You could have a look at [`more details here in the offical document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/calls-window)

**Note:**

For `WinDbg` tool you might need to get familiar with the tool functionality first. It used to use details investigation purpose.

Comment: I've just done it. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to assist you. Thanks